# Can't npm link local dependency

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-link

I'm trying to link local project `testabc123` to `myproject` using the usual approach:

```
cd testabc123
npm link
cd ../myproject
npm link testabc123
```

However I'm getting the error message:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/testabc123 - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'testabc123@*' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
```

Any ideas? My approach to linking local projects seems to be common and most people can do it successfully.

Comment: Why do you want to link? To test the module?

Comment: `testabc123` is a dependency. I want to edit the code in `testabc123` and have that reflected in `myproject` (which uses that dependency).

Comment: you have not published your module to the npm, and you are trying to fetch if from there ? This is the issue. http://registry.npmjs.org/testabc123  go and search npm registry.

Comment: Try ```npm link ../testabc123```

Comment: @ManishSoni Ok but there's many answers on this website that tell me to do exactly what I've done above, and those answers have lots of upvotes. I think something else is going on.

Comment: Your code should work *if* you have a package.json file with a `name` field of `"testabc123"`.

Answer (score 1):

*folder structure*

```
some-folder
--testabc123
--myproject
```

Go to **myproject** and just do `npm link ../testabc123` you might need admin access to do this.